# Why am i not getting the correct output

Tags: c

I am writing a piece of code to ask for two specific points in the format `P0 x y`.
If the user types in `Q` then the program terminates, for some reason I have trouble outputting the user input (`P0 x y`) into an output. When I try to run the code and type `P0 2 3` it says I have chosen points `0 2.00 3.00`.

While the desired output is `P0 2 3`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    float a, b;
    char Q, P, input;

    printf("");
    scanf("%c", &input);

    if (input == 'Q') {
        printf("quitting program");
        return (0);
    } else {
        scanf("%c" "%f" "%f", &input, &a, &b);
        printf("you have chose points: %c %f %f", input, a, b);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What is redirected input? sorry, i'm very new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use two `scanf`. First `scanf` reads `P` then second `scanf` read `0` from command line (from `stdin`). So after second `scanf`, `input = '0'`. This is reason why your program prints `0 2.00 3.00`

If you want to print out `P0` you have to use string, for example the example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a, b;
    char Q, P, input;
    char point[3] = {'\0'};
    scanf( "%c" , &input);
    point[0] = input;

    if(input=='Q')
    {
        printf("quitting program");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        scanf( "%c" "%f" "%f", &input, &a, &b);
        point[1] = input;
        printf("you have chose points: %s %f %f",point, a, b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the string is terminated by null character (`\0`). I just initialize the string by  filling with null character. You do not need to init the array as i did, but you have to add the null character at the end of string.

Comment: Okay i get it now, is there any way to incorporate say multiple inputs, but if Q was pressed it would exit the program? i tried multiple if else statements, do while and even switch and break but it doesn't work for me. Flow control of a program seems tricky at the beginning :/

Comment: you can use the `ungetc(Q, stdin);` as the answer of @anatolyg

Comment: Or you can input the string then compare  first character of this string to `Q`.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer also mentions, when checking for `Q` in input, the input byte is consumed. The C standard library provides a fix for this specific problem: you can "return" the consumed byte to the input device (keyboard buffer), and later retry reading from input.

The function is `ungetc`. It requires quite specific syntax (you should "unget" the same value as was just read; also you must use `stdin` to specify that you are working with keyboard) and only works for one byte, exactly as you need.

Here is your code with my updates and comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a, b;
    char Q; // only used for checking the "quit" condition
    char input[10]; // assuming 9 characters + terminating byte is enough

    scanf("%c", &Q);

    if(Q=='Q')
    {
        printf("quitting program");
        return (0);
    }
    else
    {
        ungetc(Q, stdin); // return one byte to the input device
        scanf( "%s" "%f" "%f", input, &a, &b); // "%s" read from the input as string now
        printf("you have chose points: %s %f %f",input, a, b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ANW, `ungetc` is nice. one UV for you.

Comment: `%s` -> `%9s` to prevent potential buffer overflow on invalid input. You should also test that the first `scanf()` returns 1 and the second `scanf` returns 3.